# get style property value using css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<p class="pen" style="color:#000">abc</p>

.pen{
color:#333
}
```

In the above html and css, the inline style has greater precedence than the class, thus `#000` will be used. But when I do `$('.pen').css('color')`, I get `#333`. How can I get the color of the current style?

Comment: This is unexpected behavior. Can you provide additional code/markup?

Comment: @WillReese what is unexpected? I guess I have given quite a lots of detail.

Comment: Your jquery should return #000

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/svaidhyanath/w0x0b47e/   i am getting rgb(0,0,0) as outpur

Comment: @Sai rgb(0,0,0) is the actual output, depending on the jquery version, but it is still the correct value.

Comment: i know that. I was merely telling OP that the value he said was coming was infact not true

Comment: OP said :: "But when I do $('.pen').css('color'), I will got the #333. " that is incorrect. the output I got on my fiddle says otherwise. So I am still trying to understand how OP got the value #333 or its equivalent as his output to the command

Comment: @EltonJamie Can create stacksnippets http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , http://jsfiddle.net where `"#333"` returned by `$(".pen").css("color")` ?

Comment: Unless OP can reproduce the issue, I vote to close this as off-topic.

Comment: This can only happen when there is another element with class `.pen` with no inline styles. **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/nrmwnu6p/)**. Else NO - **[Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/nrmwnu6p/1/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two elements with the same class

```
<p class="pen" style="">abc</p>
<p class="pen" style="color:#000">abc</p>
```

and run,

```
$('.pen').css('color')
```

The output would b `#333` or `rgb(51,51,51)`.; because the selector finds the first element matching.
So this is the problem with your code - Multiple elements with class `pen`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/nrmwnu6p/1/)

---

In case of single `pen` element or the order

```
<p class="pen" style="color:#000">abc</p>
<p class="pen" style="">abc</p>
```

the output is `#000`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/nrmwnu6p/2/)